# Account syncing every minute

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

In my `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` I try setup sync-options for an Account after `addAccountExplicitly` with following lines:

```java
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
int seconds = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.syncFrequencySeconds);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), seconds);
```

`syncFrequencySeconds` is set to 86400 (every 24 hours). But my sync-adapter is still triggered every minute. What am I doing wrong? (sync itselfs works without any problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it myself: the sync-adapter repeats when the `SyncResult.stats` do not match with the ContentResolver-Operations. As they matched, sync is triggered as expected.

Update: another issue was, that I called ContentResolver.notifyUpdate during sync-operation. removed that, and it was fine.

Comment: How did you managed to match SyncResult.stats with the SyncAdapter's contacts ContentResolver ?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean with contacts. You just need to count approbriate. For example you inserted an entry than `SyncResult.stats.numInserted++` should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I had your same problem but for a different reason. The cause of my problem was that I was using the wrong authority, after I set the right one (com.android.contacts) everything worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

My `SyncAdapter` was running every minute, not respecting the `pollFrequency` interval. I was using only queries to send local data to a remote server (on the `SyncAdapter`). I was not updating any local data on the `SyncAdapter`.

But my local data was being updated at very short intervals (receiving data from a BLE device) using another service.

To solve this issue, I had to change all `notifyChange` calls on my data provider to include the additional parameter `syncToNetwork: false` (check [notifyChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20int)) documentation).

```
//getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null, false);
```

This change did not affect my `CursorAdapter` used in the `Activity` to show the data as soon as I update the tables.

Assigning proper values to `syncResult.stats` did not solved my problem.